# Copyrighted Filming Techniques

Tags: film-techniques, film-industry

The first Matrix film had the [bullet time sequence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOitGa117_s), and people will most likely associate that technique with the movie.

[Research into bullet time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_time) shows that it was used long before The Matrix (although it was most likely called something else), and the name was also used in the video game Max Payne (the name is the same, but the technique might be different).

From the wiki link, it states:

> The term "bullet time" is a registered trademark of Warner Bros.,
>   formally established in March 2005, in connection with the video game
>   The Matrix Online.

Can a studio copyright or hold ownership over any filming technique?

Does this mean if I want to use this technique in my own movie and I would have to pay WB money before doing it?

Comment: That's not what a "trademark/copyright" is...a trademark is a **name** not a method. That's what **patents** are for.

Comment: "The **term** "bullet time" is a registered trademark" -  It seems you can use it in your movie but you can't call it "bullet time"...

Comment: @Paulie_D - Can WB patent bullet time?

Comment: @colmde - How did Max Payne (video game) get away with calling it bullet time?

Comment: What exactly would be in that patent? Remember, that you can achieve this effect using different methods.

Comment: @Mouvier - The scene in The Matrix, the camera rotating around you.

Comment: Your link: Max Payne wa´s released in 2001. Trademark "Bullet time" was registered in 2005. Before 2005 anyone could use the term.

Comment: @nsutilities ... patent law is complicated, however if they can demonstrate that they have invented a novel technology, not in any 'prior art' ... i.e. someone invented it already - then its just like any other piece of patentable technology.

Comment: To answer your question about whether WB could patent bullet time you'd have to go through the process of researching existing techniques to see what prior art exists, and whether the Matrix "bullet time" technique was novel ... or whether some substantial part of it was novel. Yes, they could attempt to patent it ... its impossible for us to say whether they would be successful.

Comment: It's considerably easier/faster to trademark a name than it is to patent a technique.  Patents typically take years to grant.

Comment: At this point, WB would be barred from patenting bullet time; you only have a year from publishing to file.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a patent agent (not practicing).

The comment about "bullet time" being a *name* that you have to license is spot on. There's nothing stopping you from copying the technique in your movie, as long as you don't call it "bullet time."

That said: if the technique is implemented in software, then the method of doing it might be patented, so that anyone else creating that effect would be *suspected* of using the patented method. That would apply to the maker of the software, not to the ultimate consumer.

The problem with Warner having a method patent (I'm not saying they do) is: let's say some other video game tools maker offers this same effect, without using the forbidden name. Now Warner has to sue them just to look at their source code, or else convince a judge that there is no possible way to implement it without infringing. Either is a tough sell.

Of course, big companies are bullies, and they might demand you take a license from them, even knowing that they have no case, because you can't afford a lawyer.

Patents are public (once they're issued), so you can always search the USPTO database for relevant patents, if you're really paranoid. However, I wouldn't if I were you. "Willful infringement" can triple the damages if it really came to that.

Comment: Whether or not the technique in question is implemented in software has nothing to do with its patentability (except insofar as many jurisdictions don't allow software to be patented at all). Plenty of non-software special effects used in movies, such as those involving physical mechanisms, are also the subject of patents.

Comment: He was talking about "bullet time" though. Can you point to some patents on non-software special effects?
Secondly, what jurisdiction relevant to movie-making does NOT allow software patents? The US certainly does.

Comment: There are easily thousands of such non-software patents. To choose just one notable example, there's US patent 3,879,115 from 1975, which describes camera mechanisms for special dissolve and fade effects. To answer your second question, the EU generally disallows software patents, and yes, it certainly supports a thriving film industry.

Comment: And your notable example is expired. As for the EU, unless things have changed in the last five years, no they do not disallow software patents.